# How to store polygons created by addDraw in variables as sf data

Tags: r, shiny, gis, r-sf

How to store polygons created by `addDrawToolbar` in variables as `sf` data

By using `addDrawToolbar`, I was able to draw polygons on the map. Is it possible to store this polygon in a variable as `sf` format?

In the subsequent processing, I intend to combine (`st_union`) with the existing polygon (Administrative district data).
Therefore, I am looking for a way to save it as `sf` format data.

If you know or have a web page that you can refer to, please let me know.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in RStudio at the console or in a Shiny app?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I'm running with the Shiny app.

Comment: You may want to try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48860161/7547327 or this: https://github.com/r-spatial/mapedit/issues/95

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!
I will check the URL immediately!